# How to get the required parameters in a controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm not sure why I couldn't find it, but I need to get the value of the required parameter in the controller. For example if the route is `/route/{param}`, and if someone entered `/route/123`, I want to get `123`:

```
public function some_method(Request $request)
{
    // get {param} value, 123
}
```

All I've seen is that it's either used for route-model-binding or that it doesn't use the `Request` (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Models\User;
 
// Route definition...
Route::get('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
 
// Controller method definition...
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

*But perhaps I don't even need `Request $request` because I can get it via the `request()` helper?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-parameters should help

Comment: If I understand, I can then change the signature of the controller's method to `public function some_method(Request $request, string $id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both `Request` parameter, value parameter or model binding, laravel is smart enough to recognize what's type of data you expect (due to giving type to the parameter). So you can do:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\YourController;
 
// Route definition...
Route::get('/route/{param}', [YourController::class, 'some_method']);
 
// Controller method definition...
public function some_method(Request $request, string $param)
{
    ... // for /route/123 $param will have '123' value
}
```

if the id that you want to get is id of some model, then you can have both `Request` and model binding:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\YourController;
use App\Models\YourModel;
 
// Route definition...
Route::get('/route/{param}', [YourController::class, 'some_method']);
 
// Controller method definition...
public function some_method(Request $request, YourModel $param)
{
    ... // for /route/123 you will get YourModel with id 123
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I don't want a model? I just want the value? Because in my case it doesn't represent a model

Comment: I added two examples, the first one answers your comment..

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice from some reason. yes, that's it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get required parameter from route so here is a good example:

`web.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

Route::get('/endpoint/{param}', [SomeController::class, 'someMethod']);
```

`SomeController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
   public function someMethod($param)
   {
      // Now you can check the value
      // by using dd()
      dd($param);
   }
}
```

**Note:** *Make sure your route parameter and function parameter must be with same name*

You can also access parameter value by using segment, here is another example:

```php
public function someMethod($param)
{
   request()->segment(2);
}
```